# How can I add more email address autocomplete sources to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, autocomplete

When I am sending an email i want thunderbird to use any means necessary to try to autocomplete the email of the recepient... or at least to look into the senders' emails in my inbox... Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try [EMail Address Crawler 3](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/email-address-crawler/).  It can extract email addresses from all your emails.

Comment: yeah i stubled on that one too but it doesnt work on thunderbird 8

Comment: The plugin does no longer work on Thunderbird 11.

Comment: So downgrade to a compatable version.